# performSegueWithIdentifier is NOT Working at all

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, identifier, segue

Hi I'm trying to push to a different view depending what a user selects. I have a table view with 4 other view controllers linked to it via push segues in the story board. All Segues are linked directly to the TableView view controller. Depending on what cell is selected, it loads the corresponding view. Heres the code I'm using:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSDictionary *dictionary = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *selectedKey = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Key"];


    if ([selectedKey isEqual:@"Driver"]){

        self.driverDetailView.wikiItem = dictionary;
        [self.driverDetailView performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDriver" sender:dictionary];
        NSLog(@"Push Driver");
    }

    if ([selectedKey isEqual:@"Team"]) {
        NSLog(@"Push Team");
    }
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Preparing For Segue");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqual:@"pushDriver"]) {
        self.driverDetailView=segue.destinationViewController;
    }

}
```

For some reason

```
 [self.driverDetailView performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDriver" sender:dictionary];
 NSLog(@"Push Driver");
```

won't allow me to set as "Self" at the beginning, i get a error saying:

> No Visible @interface for TableCell declares the selector
>   performSegueWithIdentifier

If i use "self.driverDetailView" i don't get a error, but when i select the cell nothing happens.

Heres the HorizontalTableView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HorizontalDetailView.h"
#import "HorizontalTableCell.h"
@interface HorizontalTableView : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource> {

NSDictionary *_articleDictionary;
NSMutableArray *_reusableCells;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *articleDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *reusableCells;


@end
```

Heres the HorizontalTableView.m

```
#import "HorizontalTableView.h"
#import "HorizontalTableCell.h"
#import "ControlVariables.h"
#import "HorizontalDetailView.h"

#define kHeadlineSectionHeight  26
#define kRegularSectionHeight   18

@interface HorizontalTableView ()

@end

@implementation HorizontalTableView
@synthesize articleDictionary = _articleDictionary;
@synthesize reusableCells = _reusableCells;



- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:kVerticalTableBackgroundColor];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = kCellHeight + (kRowVerticalPadding * 0.5) + ((kRowVerticalPadding * 0.5) * 0.5);
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.articleDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.articleDictionary = nil;
    self.reusableCells = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [self.articleDictionary.allKeys count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HorizontalCell";

    HorizontalTableCell *cell = (HorizontalTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[HorizontalTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    NSArray* sortedCategories = [self.articleDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSString *categoryName = [sortedCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSArray *currentCategory = [self.articleDictionary objectForKey:categoryName];

    cell.articles = currentCategory;

    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return section == 0 ? kHeadlineSectionHeight : kRegularSectionHeight;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *customSectionHeaderView;
    UILabel *titleLabel;
    UIFont *labelFont;

    if (section == 0)
    {
        customSectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, kHeadlineSectionHeight)];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, kHeadlineSectionHeight)];
        labelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    }
    else
    {
        customSectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, kRegularSectionHeight)];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, kRegularSectionHeight)];

        labelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    }

    customSectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.01176471 green:0.01176471 blue:0.01960784 alpha:0.95];

    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    titleLabel.font = labelFont;

    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    NSArray* sortedCategories = [self.articleDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSString *categoryName = [sortedCategories objectAtIndex:section];

    titleLabel.text = [categoryName substringFromIndex:1];

    [customSectionHeaderView addSubview:titleLabel];


    return customSectionHeaderView;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Preparing For Segue");
}

@end
```

The Code for HorizontalTableCell.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HorizontalDetailView.h"
#import "DriverDetailView.h"
#import "HorizontalTableView.h"
@interface HorizontalTableCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    UITableView *_horizontalTableView;
    NSMutableArray *_articles;
    HorizontalTableCell *horizontalTableCell;

}


@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *horizontalTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *articles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) HorizontalDetailView *horizontalDetailView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DriverDetailView *driverDetailView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) HorizontalTableCell *horizontalTableCell;
@end
```

The code for HorizontalTableCell.m is:

```
#import "HorizontalTableCell.h"
#import "ControlVariables.h"
#import "ArticleCell.h"
#import "HorizontalDetailView.h"
@implementation HorizontalTableCell

@synthesize horizontalTableView = _horizontalTableView;
@synthesize articles = _articles;
@synthesize horizontalDetailView;
@synthesize driverDetailView;
@synthesize horizontalTableCell;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.articles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ArticleCell *cell = (ArticleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[ArticleCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kCellWidth, kCellHeight)];
    }

    NSDictionary *currentArticle = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[currentArticle objectForKey:@"Image"]];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [currentArticle objectForKey:@"Title"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)dealloc{
    self.horizontalTableView = nil;
    self.articles = nil;
}

- (NSString *) reuseIdentifier{
    return @"HorizontalCell";
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
        self.horizontalTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kCellHeight, kTableLength)];
        self.horizontalTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.horizontalTableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.horizontalTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
        [self.horizontalTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(kRowHorizontalPadding * 0.5, kRowVerticalPadding *
                                                      0.5, kTableLength - kRowHorizontalPadding, kCellHeight)];

        self.horizontalTableView.rowHeight = kCellWidth;
        self.horizontalTableView.backgroundColor = kHorizontalTableBackgroundColor;

        self.horizontalTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        self.horizontalTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.horizontalTableView.dataSource = self;
        self.horizontalTableView.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:self.horizontalTableView];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *selectedKey = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Key"];
    // NSLog(@"Selected Key = %@",selectedKey);

    if ([selectedKey isEqual:@"Driver"]){

        self.driverDetailView.wikiItem = dictionary;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDriver" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"Push Driver");
    }

    if ([selectedKey isEqual:@"Team"]) {
        NSLog(@"Push Team");
    }

    if ([selectedKey isEqual:@"Tech"]) {
        NSLog(@"Push Tech");
    }

    if ([selectedKey isEqual:@"Track"]) {
        NSLog(@"Push Track");
    }

    //self.horizontalDetailView.wikiItem = dictionary;

    // NSLog(@"selected Array = %@",dictionary);

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Preparing For Segue");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqual:@"pushDriver"]) {
        self.driverDetailView=segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have your segues hooked up to table view cells. If that's right, I would suggest hooking them from the view controller itself to the destination view controllers and then calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDriver"];` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have all 4 segues hooked up to the view controller, and the code above already implemented in the didSelectRowatIndexPath, when i select the cell nothing happens. i can't set it to [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDriver"] because i get a error. i have to set it as [self.driverDetailView performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDriver"]

Comment: Oh my fault for not reading your code more carefully. Is driverDetailView is an instance of the class in which these methods are implemented? What it looks like from the error message is that the performSegueWithIdentifier: method is being called on your subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Yes, its being called their because thats where the didSelectRowAtIndex method is. I tried putting the didSelectRowAtIndex method in the Subclass of the UITableView but it doesn't work their. The table is a horizontal scrolling table, with a custom cell within a custom cell, just to make things a bit more complicated!

Comment: The right place for your table view delegate and data source methods is in the implementation of the view controller that owns your table view. Make sure in the header file of that view controller that you add <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>. Then your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method will notify the table view's delegate (i.e., the owning view controller) that it should performSegueWithIdentifier: which is a selector that UIViewController (and its subclasses) will recognize.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Ive checked HorizontalTableView.h and i have <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> declared. I'm still getting the error message "No visible @interface for HorizontalTableCell declares the selector" Any more code you want to see? Ill add it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: So, HorizontalTableView is a subclass of UITableView, right? And there must be a view controller that that is instantiated in? It's THAT view controller that needs to conform to the protocols. May I see the whole implementation of the view controller in which you instantiate your custom table view?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean by which view controller is instantiated in. The table view controller class is set to HorizontalTableView in the story board. It is linked to a Navigation Contoller. Ive included the implementation file to the HorizontalTableView above.

Comment: To clarify, I now understand you to mean the HorizontalTableView is a subclass of UITableViewController, not UITableView? Have you set the delegate and datasource of your table view? And your didSelectRowAtIndexPath should definitely be there with your other table view data source and delegate methods. If it was there before and if this class is a subclass of UITableViewController and you were getting no response to selection of a cell, I expect it was because the delegate and data source were not set for your table view.

Comment: Yeah HorizontalTableView is a subclass of UITableViewController. Ill include HorizontalTableView.h above. HorizontalTableCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell and this is where the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is. There is also ArticleCell which is another subclass of UITableViewCell and this used to create a custom cell within a cell to make the horizontal scrolling interface.

Comment: Okay. didSelectRowAtIndexPath definitely won't work from inside the implementation of your table view cell. It has to be in HorizontalTableView.m. If you move it there and make sure that you have set your delegate and data source for your table view (either by calling [self.tableView setDelegate:self]; [self.tableView setDataSource:self]; or by hooking up the connections in your storyboard file and it still doesn't work, let me know and I'll continue to do my best to help.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, much appreciated. i set didSelectRowAtIndexPath in both HorizontalTableView and HorizontalTableCell, i included different NSLogs in each to see which one was being called. For some reason only the log of HorizontalTableCell was showing. Ill include the code for HorizontalTableCell above.

Comment: Been looking at it a bit more, its got to be something to do with navigation controller. is it possible to call navigation controller to push the view, instead of self?

Comment: Sure I don't see why not:
DriverDetailView *ddv = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:ddv];

Comment: Thank, I've added your code but I'm still getting the same error highlighting 'self' the error is : no visible @interface for 'HorizontalTableCell' declares the selector 'storyboard' It must be because I'm not declaring something some where.... question is where?

Comment: also getting no visible @interface for 'HorizontalTableCell' declares the selector 'navigationController' aswell.

Comment: Really, the only thing that you should be doing in the implementation of your subclass of UITableViewCell is setting up the cell's attributes (subviews, etc.). Code for navigation and population of table cells should not be in the implementation of the cell itself, but rather in the view controller that owns the table view that owns the cell. If you want to compress your project and dropbox it to me, I can look through it tonight and I think I could help you get this really sorted out.

Comment: Ok thanks, to help me create the horizontal scrolling i used a tutorial i got here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2 I've adapted it a bit for my needs and made it work with ARC and storyboard but the principle is the same, you can get a copy of the project at the bottom of the tutorial page. Probaly help you get a better understanding of my problem. thanks for you help.

Comment: IM me at geraldwburke@gmail.com either through gchat or AIM, I've built something like this before and I think I can help but our conversation is way too long to continue in comments.